# How can I organize my data into a new table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to organize my data with a new table that must contain three columns respectively: date, ticker and value. I have this code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
stocks = ['CTKA3.SA', 'PNVL3.SA', 'SHUL4.SA', 'SMTO3.SA']
initial_dt = '2019-01-01'
data = wb.DataReader(stocks, data_source='yahoo', start = initial_dt)['Adj Close']
```

The code gives me a table that contains for each ticker a column and a date column with the value in that day. I want just one column of ticker and not for each ticker.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean **date**, ticker and value?

Comment: data = data.stack()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
data=data.stack()
```

produces

```
Date        Symbols 
2019-01-02  CTKA3.SA      4.890000
            PNVL3.SA    306.722626
            SHUL4.SA      6.837185
            SMTO3.SA     17.927473
2019-01-03  CTKA3.SA      4.890000
                           ...    
2020-02-13  SMTO3.SA     27.850000
2020-02-14  CTKA3.SA     12.680000
            PNVL3.SA    690.000000
            SHUL4.SA     14.390000
            SMTO3.SA     28.799999
Length: 1116, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Can I repeat the date for those empty rows? For example: Date        Symbols 
2019-01-02  CTKA3.SA      4.890000
2019-01-02  PNVL3.SA    306.722626
2019-01-02  SHUL4.SA      6.837185
2019-01-02  SMTO3.SA     17.927473
2019-01-03  CTKA3.SA      4.890000
                           ...    
2020-02-13  SMTO3.SA     27.850000
2020-02-14  CTKA3.SA     12.680000
Length: 1116, dtype: float64

Comment: `data = data.stack().reset_index().set_index('Date')`